# During a wheelie, is there a braking effect on the back wheel of the scooter that is triggered physically when the bike is close to vertical?

Tags: torque, signal-processing

When someone does a wheelie using a motorcycle (scooter), it looks to me like something is stopping the the motorcycle from tipping over backwards so far that it crashes. Is there some sort of (built in?) braking effect on the back wheel of the motorcycle that comes into play, without the rider doing anything, when the bike is close to vertical?

I've seen so many wheelies where the bike seems to stop at vertical automatically. The teenagers doing the wheelies don't look like the sort of people to be that skilled. And they *never* tip over backwards. It seems unlikely that they would get that skill without ever tipping over. And it really looks like they are *trying* to tip the bike over backwards but the bike won't let them. I thought it might be a built in feature of the bikes, to make doing wheelies easier and/or safer, or maybe just an unintended effect.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  I'd argue it's a question about the physics of wheelies, although your point is a reasonable one. What would be the best way to move to it the correct site? But aren't the throttle and rear wheel brake pedal operated by the *right* hand and the *right* foot, respectively?

Comment: @I've edited the question in light of your comments, so it leaves open the matter of what the cause of the effect is, either something fortuitous from physics or a design feature.